# Trouble booting into Ubuntu with UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi

I was hoping you all could help. Ive done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on my Dell laptop. When I shut down then restart I get an error msg on my Dell screen which reads "Start PXE over IPv6 -- Start PXE over IPv4 -- PXE-E18 server responce timeout". This lasts on the screen for about three to four minutes then successfully boots into my OS. I checked my BIOS screen and boot order. Under "boot list options" UEFI is selected, but my HD is not in the boot order. It only shows the UEFI IP4 and UEFI IP6.

HOWEVER, if I hit f12 at startup and select "boot from hard drive" in Legacy mode, it boots right into my OS. My question is, is it safe to change the boot list options in BIOS to Legacy instead of UEFI?

**UPDATE**
I think I figured out my issue. When I installed, I booted onto the Ubuntu Live DVD in Legacy and not UEFI. Thus installing it in Legacy mode. Does this sound like what could be causing the issue? Do I need to reinstall in UEFI mode or can I safely still use Legacy?  What about installing GRUB in UEFI from the Live DVD?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** I reinstalled in UEFI mode and now it boots into my OS as it should. The issue was cause by initially installing in legacy BIOS by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your BIOS menu there must be some command to allow you to disable that PXE (network) boot. Either this or move PXE in **boot menu - boot devices order** to the last position after CD/DVD-ROM, HDD and USB.